# Close Firefox on click on image

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser, onclick

I am looking for a way to close Firefox from within an html page.
When looking for a solution I saw that most pages suggested something like:

```
<a href="javascript:window.close();">Close</a>
```

This is only working for tabs and in Firefox this method does not seem to work at all.

Is there a way to close Firefox completely after clicking on a website element?

Thanks!

Comment: That would give some very bad user experience. Imagine someone has 10 tabs open that have nothing to do with the actual website the person is viewing and than with some magic everything closes.

Comment: Why would you like to do that?!? Terrible idea. What is the initial problem leading to that drastic measure?

Comment: I understand your concerns. I need this for a research project where participants are confronted with a website in the lab. Therefore it is a somewhat unnatural setting. Obviously this does not make much sense for websites in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can only close windows if you have their handle. That means your page needs to be the one that opened them (or you somehow passed the handle around).